# 2to3.6: python conversion hanging

Tags: python-3.x, python-2to3

hi I have some `python code` which is generated dynamically which produces python2 code and this python generated code is executed and it's output is then used by downstream application, the problem I have is my code conversion seems to be hanging at these lines

```
RefactoringTool: Files that were modified:
RefactoringTool: x.py
```

can someone take a look and let me know what could be wrong.

```
python_code = """
def greet(name):
    print("Hello, {0}!".format(name))
print "What's your name?"
name = input()
greet(name)
"""
with open('x.py', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write(python_code)
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["2to3-3.6", "-w", 'x.py', "/dev/null"])
op = subprocess.check_output(["python3",  'x.py'])
subprocess.run("rm", "-rf" ,"x.py")
subprocess.run("rm", "-rf" ,"x.py.bak")
print(op)
```

Comment: The code in that string already is valid Python3. What is there to convert? By the way, you can execute scripts and delete files without using subprocess

Comment: @OneCricketeer ok I have updated question

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need `/dev/null`?

Comment: No I do not need /dev/null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing the `x.py` file, which is waiting for `input()`.

Press enter, and your script will end